# Javascript Tic Tac Toe- AI issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a simple game of Tic Tac Toe with an AI that can only win or draw. I have taken the brute force approach to building this AI as the minmax approach is fairly complicated seen as I am new to javascript. The AI seems to work but the problem I have is that it makes too many moves when it is the AI's turn, so sometimes the AI will take two squares when I want it to take only one and sometimes it won't make any moves at all.

Code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var userChoice;
  var computerChoice;
  var dialogBox = $("#dialogBox");
  var s1 = $("#top-left");
  var s2 = $("#top");
  var s3 = $("#top-right");
  var s4 = $("#left");
  var s5 = $("#middle");
  var s6 = $("#right");
  var s7 = $("#bottom-left");
  var s8 = $("#bottom");
  var s9 = $("#bottom-right");
  var turn = 1; // turn 1=computer turn 2=user

  var countMoves = 9;

  renderDialog();
  dialogChoice(); // user chooses X or O
  move();

  // make dialog box
  function renderDialog() {
    var winW = window.innerWidth;
    var centerDialog = (winW / 2) - (600 * 0.5); // to center
    dialogBox.css("display", "block")
    dialogBox.css("left", centerDialog + "px");
    dialogBox.css("top", "100px")
  }
  // make dialog interactive
  function dialogChoice() {
    var cross = $('#cross');
    var circle = $('#circle');

    cross.on("click", function() {
      dialogBox.css("display", "none");
      userChoice = "X";
      computerChoice = "O";
      computerRandom();

    });
    circle.on("click", function() {
      dialogBox.css("display", "none");
      userChoice = "O";
      computerChoice = "X";
      computerRandom();

    });
  }

  // make function to allow user to click on square to move
  function move() {

    $("#top-left").on("click", function() {
      if ($("#top-left").html() === '') {
        $("#top-left").text(userChoice);
        turn = 1;
        userTurn();
      };
    });
    $("#top").on("click", function() {
      if ($("#top").html() === '') {
        $("#top").text(userChoice);
        turn = 1;
        userTurn();
      };
    });
    $("#top-right").on("click", function() {
      if ($("#top-right").html() === '') {
        $("#top-right").text(userChoice);
        turn = 1;
        userTurn();
      }
    });
    $("#left").on("click", function() {
      if ($("#left").html() === '') {
        $("#left").text(userChoice);
        turn = 1;
        userTurn();
      };
    });
    $("#middle").on("click", function() {
      if ($("#middle").html() === '') {
        $("#middle").text(userChoice);
        turn = 1;
        userTurn();
      };
    });
    $("#right").on("click", function() {
      if ($("#right").html() === '') {
        $("#right").text(userChoice);
        turn = 1;
        userTurn();
      };
    });
    $("#bottom-left").on("click", function() {
      if ($("#bottom-left").html() === '') {
        $("#bottom-left").text(userChoice);
        turn = 1;
        userTurn();
      };
    });
    $("#bottom").on("click", function() {
      if ($("#bottom").html() === '') {
        $("#bottom").text(userChoice);
        turn = 1;
        userTurn();
      };
    });
    $("#bottom-right").on("click", function() {
      if ($("#bottom-right").html() === '') {
        $("#bottom-right").text(userChoice);
        turn = 1;
        userTurn();
      };
    });

  };

  // switch turns on every round aswell as check for gameover tests.
  function userTurn() {
    computerAI();

    computerRandom();

    countMoves--;
    console.log(turn);

    if (isWinner() || draw()) {
      countMoves = 9;
      restartGame();
    }

  };

  //check for winner
  function isWinner() {
    var result = false;
    // first row
    if (s1.text() == "X" && s2.text() == "X" && s3.text() == "X" || s1.text() == "O" && s2.text() == "O" && s3.text() == "O") {
      s1.css("background", "green");
      s2.css("background", "green");
      s3.css("background", "green");

      result = true;
      return result;
    }

    //seconds row
    if (s4.text() == "X" && s5.text() == "X" && s6.text() == "X" || s4.text() == "O" && s5.text() == "O" && s6.text() == "O") {
      s4.css("background", "green");
      s5.css("background", "green");
      s6.css("background", "green");

      result = true;
      return result;
    }

    //third row   
    if (s7.text() == "X" && s8.text() == "X" && s9.text() == "X" || s7.text() == "O" && s8.text() == "O" && s9.text() == "O") {
      s7.css("background", "green");
      s8.css("background", "green");
      s9.css("background", "green");

      result = true;
      return result;
    }

    // first column
    if (s1.text() == "X" && s4.text() == "X" && s7.text() == "X" || s1.text() == "O" && s4.text() == "O" && s7.text() == "O") {
      s1.css("background", "green");
      s4.css("background", "green");
      s7.css("background", "green");

      result = true
      return result;
    }
    //second column 
    if (s2.text() == "X" && s5.text() == "X" && s8.text() == "X" || s2.text() == "O" && s5.text() == "O" && s8.text() == "O") {
      s2.css("background", "green");
      s5.css("background", "green");
      s8.css("background", "green");

      result = true
      return result;
    }

    //third column
    if (s3.text() == "X" && s6.text() == "X" && s9.text() == "X" || s3.text() == "O" && s6.text() == "O" && s9.text() == "O") {
      s3.css("background", "green");
      s6.css("background", "green");
      s9.css("background", "green");

      result = true
      return result;
    }

    // first diagonal
    if (s1.text() == "X" && s5.text() == "X" && s9.text() == "X" || s1.text() == "O" && s5.text() == "O" && s9.text() == "O") {
      s1.css("background", "green");
      s5.css("background", "green");
      s9.css("background", "green");

      result = true
      return result;
    }

    //second diagonal
    if (s3.text() == "X" && s5.text() == "X" && s7.text() == "X" || s3.text() == "O" && s5.text() == "O" && s7.text() == "O") {
      s3.css("background", "green");
      s5.css("background", "green");
      s7.css("background", "green");

      result = true
      return result;
    }

  };

  function draw() {
    var result = false;
    if (countMoves == 0) {
      result = true;

    }
    return result;
  }

  function restartGame() {

    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".col-xs-4").text('');
      $(".col-xs-4").css("background", "red");

      if (s5.text() == '') {
        s5.text(computerChoice)

      };

    }, 2000)
  }

  function computerAI() {

    countMoves--;
    if (turn == 1) {
      computerWin()
    };
    if (turn == 1) {
      computerBlock()
    };

    if (turn == 1) {
      computerFork()
    };

    if (turn == 1) {
      blockFork()
    }
    if (turn == 1) {
      computerRandom();
    }

  };

  // computer will block opponent move
  function computerBlock() {
    // first Row1
    if (s1.text() == userChoice && s2.text() == userChoice && s3.text() == '') {

      s3.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //first Row2
    if (s3.text() == userChoice && s2.text() == userChoice && s1.text() == '') {
      s1.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //first Row3
    if (s1.text() == userChoice && s3.text() == userChoice && s2.text() == '') {
      s2.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //second Row
    if (s4.text() == userChoice && s5.text() == userChoice && s6.text() == '') {
      s6.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //second Row2
    if (s6.text() == userChoice && s5.text() == userChoice && s4.text() == '') {
      s4.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //second Row3
    if (s6.text() == userChoice && s4.text() == userChoice && s5.text() == '') {
      s5.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };

    //third row
    if (s7.text() == userChoice && s8.text() == userChoice && s9.text() == '') {
      s9.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //third row2
    if (s9.text() == userChoice && s8.text() == userChoice && s7.text() == '') {
      s7.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //third Row3
    if (s9.text() == userChoice && s7.text() == userChoice && s8.text() == '') {
      s8.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //first column
    if (s1.text() == userChoice && s3.text() == userChoice && s7.text() == '') {
      s7.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //first column2
    if (s7.text() == userChoice && s4.text() == userChoice && s1.text() == '') {
      s1.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //first column3
    if (s1.text() == userChoice && s7.text() == userChoice && s4.text() == '') {
      s4.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //second column
    if (s2.text() == userChoice && s5.text() == userChoice && s8.text() == '') {
      s8.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //second column2
    if (s8.text() == userChoice && s5.text() == userChoice && s2.text() == '') {
      s2.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //second column3
    if (s2.text() == userChoice && s8.text() == userChoice && s5.text() == '') {
      s5.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //third column
    if (s3.text() == userChoice && s6.text() == userChoice && s9.text() == '') {
      s9.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //third column2
    if (s9.text() == userChoice && s6.text() == userChoice && s3.text() == '') {
      s3.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //third column3
    if (s3.text() == userChoice && s9.text() == userChoice && s6.text() == '') {
      s6.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    // first diagonal
    if (s1.text() == userChoice && s5.text() == userChoice) {
      s9.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //first diagonal 2
    if (s9.text() == userChoice && s5.text() == userChoice && s1.text() == '') {
      s1.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    // first diagonal 3
    if (s1.text() == userChoice && s9.text() == userChoice && s5.text() == '') {
      s5.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };

    //second diagonal
    if (s3.text() == userChoice && s5.text() == userChoice && s7.text() == '') {
      s7.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //second diagonal2
    if (s7.text() == userChoice && s5.text() == userChoice && s3.text() == '') {
      s3.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //second diagonal 3
    if (s7.text() == userChoice && s3.text() == userChoice && s5.text() == '') {
      s5.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
  };

  // computer will make move to win
  function computerWin() {
    // take third for win
    // first Row1
    if (s1.text() == computerChoice && s2.text() == computerChoice && s3.text() == '') {
      s3.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //first Row2
    if (s3.text() == computerChoice && s2.text() == computerChoice) {
      s1.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //second Row
    if (s4.text() == computerChoice && s5.text() == computerChoice && s6.text() == '') {
      s6.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //second Row2
    if (s6.text() == computerChoice && s5.text() == computerChoice && s4.text() == '') {
      s4.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //third row
    if (s7.text() == computerChoice && s8.text() == computerChoice && s9.text() == '') {
      s9.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //third row2
    if (s9.text() == computerChoice && s8.text() == computerChoice && s7.text() == '') {
      s7.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //first column
    if (s1.text() == computerChoice && s3.text() == computerChoice && s7.text() == '') {
      s7.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //first column2
    if (s7.text() == computerChoice && s4.text() == computerChoice && s1.text() == '') {
      s1.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //second column
    if (s2.text() == computerChoice && s5.text() == computerChoice && s8.text() == '') {
      s8.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //second column2
    if (s8.text() == computerChoice && s5.text() == computerChoice && s2.text() == '') {
      s2.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //third column
    if (s3.text() == computerChoice && s6.text() == computerChoice && s9.text() == '') {
      s9.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //third column2
    if (s9.text() == computerChoice && s6.text() == computerChoice && s3.text() == '') {
      s3.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    // first diagonal
    if (s1.text() == computerChoice && s5.text() == computerChoice && s9.text() == '') {
      s9.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //first diagonal2
    if (s9.text() == computerChoice && s5.text() == computerChoice && s1.text() == '') {
      s1.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //second diagonal
    if (s3.text() == computerChoice && s5.text() == computerChoice && s7.text() == '') {
      s7.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //second diagonal2
    if (s7.text() == computerChoice && s5.text() == computerChoice && s3.text() == '') {
      s3.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
  };
  // computer make move to create a fork
  function computerFork() {
    // fork1
    if (s1.text() == computerChoice && s5.text() == computerChoice && s3.text() == '') {
      s3.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //fork2
    if (s3.text() == computerChoice && s5.text() == computerChoice && s1.text() == '') {
      s1.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //fork3
    if (s7.text() == computerChoice && s5.text() == computerChoice && s9.text() == '') {
      s9.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //fork4
    if (s9.text() == computerChoice && s5.text() == computerChoice && s7.text() == '') {
      s7.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };

  };

  function blockFork() {
    // fork1
    if (s1.text() == userChoice && s5.text() == userChoice && s3.text() == '') {
      s3.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //fork2
    if (s3.text() == userChoice && s5.text() == userChoice && s1.text() == '') {
      s1.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //fork3
    if (s7.text() == userChoice && s5.text() == userChoice && s9.text() == '') {
      s9.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
    //fork4
    if (s9.text() == userChoice && s5.text() == userChoice && s7.text() == '') {
      s7.text(computerChoice);
      turn = 2;
    };
  };

  function computerRandom() {

    var squareArr = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9];
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);

    if (squareArr[randomNum].text() == '') {
      squareArr[randomNum].text(computerChoice);
      squareArr.splice(randomNum, 1);
      turn = 2;

    }
  };
```

});

example:http://codepen.io/aliz16/full/yJgQQd/

Comment: I recommend separating your UI / presentation from the underlying logic / model.

Comment: This is too broad. I don't think anyone is going to browse through pages of code to first understand what it is doing and then find the problems with it.

Comment: I understand, I guess what I wanted to know was why the AI was making so many moves but on closer inspection in the computerAI function I think the computer might be implementing all of the functions I have put in there instead of picking just one and then ending the function. All I want is the computer to make just one move based on the criteria in the computer AI function and the end the function. I think I might have to use "return" in order to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Check you functions that play for the computer.

Let's take computerWin for an example. What is stopping the function from making multiple marks? Several Conditions could be true. Delegating the turn doesn't stop the checks.

P.S. not all lines are correct either.